# Maximum Length of a SQL Query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written a SQL Query in Oracle that has 529 lines.

Is this query not too long to be sucessfuly executed?

[image]

Comment: 529 is no problem at all. I guess Oracle can return many billions of rows. Or trillions.

Comment: Not a result row, in query row

Comment: 529 rows of what?

Comment: @Rajat in my select query

Comment: I don't think there is a limit as restrictive as 529. See here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21643/limit.htm#TTREF457 

What happens when you run that code? Does it return an error? If so, please include it in the question.

Comment: @Rajat no no not error, I just asked the question because I'm a new worker in SQL and i'm scared with my code lol

Comment: @Vanessa0612 529 is really not a lot of code if you are actually building a decently involved process for pulling the data. I think you should worry less about length of your code and more that you're scared. Make sure you understand every single line of code and that the output is indeed what you had expected to get. Over time, you'll learn how to write code that's more concise and yet performant and readable, but for now make sure you're confident about the code, the underlying business logic it follows, and its output.

Comment: @Rajat, thank you so much for your tips. Have a good day

Comment: As a word of advice don't merge old join syntax from the 80s with modern one. Avoid the commas.

Comment: @TheImpaler Commas ? in the synthax ?

Comment: Yes, commas. For example: `... = SR.SERVICE_REQUEST_ID),` -- Do you see that comma at the end? You are mixing modern syntax (`LEFT JOIN`) with old syntax `table1, table2`.

Comment: @TheImpaler Ok I see , you know one website for optimizer query syntax ?

Comment: Physically the complexity of a query is limited by the RAM, and its performance by the CPU. Practically a query is limited by my comprehension of the logic happening in the query (which ends way before the RAM). Having a longer but easily readable and understandable query is better than cramming all conditions and categorizing in the fewest lines possible

Comment: @Vanessa0612 welcome to SO. please make sure to not use screen capture for your code, and use code instead. Ty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Oracle Documentation of the [Database Limits](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/logical-database-limits.html#GUID-685230CF-63F5-4C5A-B8B0-037C566BDA76) does not specifiy an exact limit for the length of a SQL query. (Note that the number of lines is not revelant, but the total length of the query string.

There is only this **Note** there

> The limit on how long a SQL statement can be depends on many factors, including database configuration, disk space, and memory

You can be sure there is no such 4000 character (as for VARCHAR2) limit there and 500+ line query is not unusual.

You will have a hard work to write a query that cross the length limit.

More "realistic" is that you cross some other limitation such as the *255 subqueries in the WHERE clause*.

Check the link provided above for Oracle 19 for the full list of the limitations.

So far more important to check the propper length od the query is this **test**:

*review the query after 14 days and if it is well readable and understandable  - it has a right length*!

Answer (score -1):

You can limit the number of rows returned from your query using the rownum clause

```
--to get any ten rows from your query output..
select *
  from <your query>
where rownum<=10;
```

Comment: not a problem, just I think my query it's so much complex ....

Comment: @Vanessa0612 can i ask why the downvote, the original question the OP had was how to limit the number of rows?

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph i think there is a misunderstanding here. OP was not trying to limit the number of rows of the *output* but of the *query*. Your answer is syntactically correct but it does not address the actual question.

Beside - 529 rows aren't a challenge for the DB at all. Plus as I guess not all lines contain really code and you're using a clean indentation (which is mandatory when writing more complex queries).

Comment: @procra when the question was initially composed, the post was different, it talked about limiting the number of rows and my answer was in lines with that answer. Now it looks different that my answer and the explanation isnt matching up with the edited question. However when i got a downvote, on my answer that's when i pointed it out specifically.